# Customizing authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

My Controller class is decorated with an AuthorizeAttribute to protect the actions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User Level 2")]
public class BuyController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Anytime an action is invoked, but the user is not in at least the role "User Level 2", the user is automatically redirected to the login page with a URL like this:

http://localhost:1436/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fBuy

If the user is already logged in, but doesn't have the right security level, this is not an optimal behavior! It would make more sense to display a page which informs the user about the missing level instead of showing the login page.

What can I do to customize this behavior?

Is it possible to pass the required user level to the Login action somehow?

Comment: There is another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can build your own authorize attribute like this:

```
public class ClubAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  if (filterContext.Cancel && filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
  {
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
      new RouteValueDictionary {
      { "clubShortName", filterContext.RouteData.Values[ "clubShortName" ] },
      { "controller", "Account" },
      { "action", "Login" },
      { "ReturnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
    });
  }
}
}
```

I used this to redirect to a specific club in a club membership site I am building.  You could adapt this to your need.  BTW, in my case I do redirect to the login page, but I check to see if the user is authorized and if so, display a message that they don't have the correct permissions.  No doubt you could also add something to ViewData or TempData to display on the page, but I haven't tried that

**EDIT**
AuthorizationContext.Cancel doesn't exist anymore in RC. "filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult" seems to be enough : [What happened to filterContext.Cancel (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505653/what-happened-to-filtercontext-cancel-asp-net-mvc/505679#505679)

Comment: filterContext doesn't seem to have a Cancel member. Am I missing some extension methods?

Answer (score 1):

Time has long passed since the last answer.

Since 2009, a lot of progress has been made in the authorization space. In particular, OASIS (the ones behind SAML) have standardized XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language.

XACML gives developers:

- a usage pattern
- an architecture
- a flexible authorization policy language

XACML is in line with attribute-based access control which NIST recommends be adopted in applications nowadays.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520401/net-webapi-centralized-authorization/19545001#19545001) for more details.