# Show 404 error page after [Authorize] failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, authorization

I have an action I want to restrict only to role "Admin". I did it like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

After manually going under Controller/Edit/1 path I'm redirected to login page. Well, that isn't bad maybe, but I want to show 404 instead of it and try to stick using attributes for it. Is that possible?

Comment: Just a comment, perhaps you should show a 401 or 403 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: oh, formally you're right, but I don't want others to know that the action name is correct (that would probably suggest it)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [Asp.net MVC Authorize attribute, redirect to custom “no rights” page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4457476/267448)

Comment: Duplicate or not, Darin's answer is a good one that I don't think I've seen before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Sure, you could write a custom authorize attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/401.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Remark: you probably want to show a 401 or 403 page if the user is not authorized instead of 404 which is for file not found.

Comment: It may be helpful for others to know that this may be combined with another of [Darin's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314673/user-is-in-role-admin-but-authorizeroles-admin-wont-authenticate). I have done just that and it works brilliantly. To combine the two include the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method from this answer in the same class as the `OnAuthorization` method from the other answer. Keep up the good work Darin!

Comment: @Ben can you share your solution?

Comment: @Daniel I can try! It's been 2 years since I looked at this code but I'll do a new answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

In response to @Daniel's comment on my comment to @Darin's answer this is my implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies == null ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null
        )
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        var authCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');

        var userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name);
        var userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, roles);

        filterContext.HttpContext.User = userPrincipal;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    // Redirects unauthorized users to a "401 Unauthorized" page
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error/401.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```