# Automatic login of user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

I am creating a web app where in one of the functionality I need is to automatically login the user for which cookie is not expired yet. Below code is my starting point -

```
HttpCookie curCookie = Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];

if (curCookie != null)
{
      FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(curCookie.Value);
      var userName = ticket.Name;

      using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
      {         
          // what to do here?

      }
}
```

If the cookie has expired, then I can't help it. But if it has not, then I can think of three approaches to follow -

1) I can connect to db (webpages_Membership) and get corresponding password, decrypt and then attempt to login.

2) I can store the hashed password with the cookie and retrieve it and login.

3) I can store the hashed password in UserProfile table and as I already have a dbset in my code, I can use it to query and login.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and a little confused about which is the right approach for me. If there are any in-built functions to retrieve passwords, please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at these http://www.asp.net/identity . You can set cookie expiration time and so on...

Comment: if ASPXAUTH cookie is present then the user is automatically authenticated and no extra steps are needed. It is how forms authentication works by default.

Comment: @MajoB It is not working for me that way. Do I need any configuration setup or anything else for it to work?

Comment: @Sam how to implement custom form authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329197/custom-form-authentication-authorization-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc