# How to authorize an OpenID user on MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissions, openid, membership, dotnetopenauth

I'm looking at the `[Authorize(Roles = "DefaultUser")]` available in MVC, but I can't seem to figure out if I can use it with DotNetOpenAuth.

I'm using OpenID as my sole membership provider, but I have a few generic items in a UserProfile table.  I don't want anyone except the appropriate user to be able to access the edit controller.

EXAMPLE:
UserID **2** should **not** be able to access `/Users/Edit/1`, but they **CAN** access `/Users/Edit/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit/Rewrite for clearer understanding**

```
public class AdvancedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
            public string RouteDataValue
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                if(base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
                {
                    MvcHandler mvcHandler = httpContext.CurrentHandler as MvcHandler;
                    if (mvcHandler != null)
                    {
                        var paramValue = mvcHandler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[RouteDataValue];
                        if (paramValue != null)
                        {
                            // Inside this IF-statement is where you'll have to customize for your code.

                            //I use the default user from HttpContext
                            string UserPrincipalName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                            // I use email as login name, and here I try to fetch a user from my repository with that email.
                            User userObject = new Repository<User>().GetOne(x => x.Email == UserPrincipalName);
                            // If I find a user, and that user's UserID is equal to the value in paramValue, it's Ok! Otherwise, not.
                            return (userObject != null && userObject.UserID.ToString() == paramValue.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
    }
```

And then, using it:

```
// Example usage (for instance from UserController)
[AdvancedAuthorize(RouteDataValue="userID")]
public ActionResult Edit(int userID)
{
     // everything as normal
}

[AdvancedAuthorize(RouteDataValue="userEmail")]
public ActionResult Delete(string userEmail)
{
     // everything as normal
}
```

Of course, for it to work, `userID` and `userEmail` in the action examples need to be bound by the modelbinder (the parameters have to exist in the `RouteData.Values`) for it to work.

Comment: does this get put in `void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: No. You create your UserIDAuthorizeAttribute (or equivalent) which extends AuthorizeAttribute and overrides AuthorizeCore. There, you check if(base.AuthorizeCore(context)) { ...put code above here ... }

Comment: I'm sorry... I really haven't a hot clue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that `[Authorize(Roles = "DefaultUser")]` means that people can edit only their own profile. It rather means that everyone in the DefaultUser role can edit profiles... Here is a discussion about it, that is pretty much the same question: [asp.net mvc authorization using roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390930/asp-net-mvc-authorization-using-roles)

EDIT:
Ok, then your problem is that roles and identity does not work with OpenID? The Authorize thing works only if the `HttpContext.Current.User` contains the right principal. If you use OpenID this does not happen out of the box, but you have to do something like this in your Global.asax:

```
void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        string encTicket = authCookie.Value;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);
            YourAppIdentity id = new YourAppIdentity(ticket);
            string username = ticket.Name;
            string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
            GenericPrincipal prin = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            HttpContext.Current.User = prin;
        }
    }
}
```

where YourAppIdentity should be something that implements IIdentity...

Comment: No I realize that. I probably should have used `[Authorize(Users = "DefaultUser")]` in my example