# Is there a way to validate that the credentials given for the database have CRUD rights?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Waht would be a good way, using either EntityFramework methods or else, to validate that the credentials given have enough rights to do CRUD actions on the database?

Comment: Attempt the CRUD actions and catch any exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself but you could try adding `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`  (Oracle) to your context and query against it to see if the user (GRANTEE) has related privilege(s).

For SQL Server privileges, you might refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database) and work on the idea.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` attribute which is used to restrict access by callers to an action method.

Here it is an example that shows you how to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11494091/5914627

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: No way related to what OP is asking!

Comment: The question asks about an checking that application using Entity Framework has permissions on a database. This answer is about restricting users of an ASP.NET web application. The two scenarios are completely unrelated.