# Can I use ASP.NET Identity even if I don't have users table and doesn't store user info in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I'm creating an app wherein authorization comes from another web app and I'm not allowed to save users data on my own database, what happens is the user will log-in on their app and they will redirect the user to my app -if they have access. The app will then pass info to my application. One of the info is the user role and I'm thinking if I can use it to customize Identity (function). Currently, I'm saving them on Session and it's just a lot of work and if else statement.

If I can do such a thing, how?

Comment: Why use Identity if you can't store ANY user info? What feature does it bring you that you want?

These might also be worth a read


https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oidc


https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/other-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: My app has a level of access and I only store their user roles in session. I want to use the function similar to Identity and Auth (e.g [Authorize],[AllowAnonymous], and Authorize("Admin") etc.) If its not possible, maybe can I recreate/override such function on my own?  I want to write much cleaner than multiple if else condition

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the repetition of your auth if/else code?
If so, just make your own custom auth attribute:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493873/how-to-implement-custom-authorize-attribute-for-the-following-case